# do I put [[maybe unused]] on function declarations or definitions?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, pragma, c++17

C++17 introduces the attribute [[[maybe_unused]]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).
I assume this a standardized version of GCC and Clang's:    [__attribute__((unused))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

For unused functions that I don't want to see a warning from,
should I be specifying the attribute on

*function declarations?*

```
void maybe_used_function() [[maybe_unused]];
```

or *function definitions?*

```
void maybe_used_function() [[maybe_unused]] {
  /* impl */
}
```

Either one?  Both?
Will the effect be the same on both the standardized and compiler specific attributes?
I can't find any clear documentation on placement behaviour, and what the common practice is.

---

When I place the attribute before the function body in a definition, GCC and clang give an error:

```
void function();
int main(){}
void function() __attribute__((unused)) {}
```

**warning: GCC does not allow 'unused' attribute in this position
      on a function definition [-Wgcc-compat]
void function() __attribute__((unused)) {**

---

However, the attribute can be placed in two other places without error:

```
__attribute__((unused)) void __attribute__((unused)) function() {}
```

Maybe one of these ways is how I'm expected to use the attribute on function definitions?

Comment: Did you *try* and see what the compiler actually says?   AFAIK, the attributes go on the declarations *only*, but I didn't double check the standard text.

Comment: @JesperJuhl : The compiler is wrong in this case and this is far from unusual, especially when discussing _upcoming_ language features that may or may not be implemented correctly (or at all).

Comment: @ildjarn the GCC error came from `__attribute__((unused))` not `[[maybe_unused]]`.  Clang seems to do the same.

Comment: I wonder why it is important to mark a function [[maybe_unused]]? Shouldn't it be used on variables?

Comment: if you have an inaccessible function from outside a translation unit, you can get a compiler warning for it not being used.  Attributing the function prevents the warning.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From N4606, [dcl.attr.unused]¶4:

> A name or entity declared without the `maybe_unused` attribute can later be redeclared with the attribute and vice versa. An entity is considered marked after the first declaration that marks it.

Since a function definition is a declaration ([dcl.dcl]¶1), this means you can put it in either place and it will behave the same.

(It makes sense to be allowed in both places since the attribute only actually affects the *definition*, but because the attribute can serve as self-documentation it is also *permitted* on the declaration.)

Comment: upvotes from other answers should be applied here instead. very clear and short answer.

Answer (score 32):

Neither.
In

```
[[attr1]] void [[attr2]] f [[attr3]] () [[attr4]] {}
```

- `attr1` and `attr3` appertain (or apply) to `f` itself.
- `attr2` appertains to the preceding type, `void`.
- `attr4` appertains to `f`'s type ("function of `()` returning `void`), not `f`.

You want `maybe_unused` to appertain to `f`, so you can put it in position 1 or 3, but not 2 or 4.

[@ildjarn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38516575/2756719) covers the rest.

For GCC's `__attribute__`, you'll have to check its documentation.

Comment: So the const in `const T & get();` applies to `get()` and not to `T&`? Not sure about that...

Comment: We are talking about attributes here. `const` is not an attribute.